# How to extract text(article) from a URL received in a JSON response

Tags: android, json, api

I am very new to Android and currently I am developing an app which displays all the editorial articles from Indian Newspapers.
Till now, I have learnt to extract title,date,author,description from the received JSON response from the newspaper's api.
But in the content, they only provide a url.
I do not know how to extract the full article from the URL. 
How can I do that? in the given image below,url is provided for the content.
[image: In this image, url is provided for the content]

Answer (score 0):

The more simple solution is to open the url and get the content. You can do this with the following code:

```
InputStream input = new URL(<the returned url>).openStream();
```

In the InputStream you will have the code returned from the url.

But if you are trying to show the article to the user, you can have a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) if you want to show the content inside your app, or call the user browser app with a intent:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(<the returned url>));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: I can try the Webview approach but what I want to do is to display the title and the content in the app screen and nothing else just like Quora does in its app (Bold title with normal text below it) that is why I was avoiding webview. I will try your code and get back to you if it works for me. Thank you very much ! :)